# iOS XCode getting IDEPseudoTerminalDomain error 1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying build a app for iOS using XCode.
The app works fine on iPhone simulator but before running it throws error "IDEPseudoTerminalDomain error 1". Don't know why it is causing this.

If I try to run all on iPad simulator then it doesn't open simulator at all.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEPseudoTerminalDomain error 1.)
```

Please can you tell me why this error is coming and how to avoid it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wii you please share Full error details

Comment: restarting Xcode worked for me...

Comment: might be a xcode error

Comment: @Vikas Khengare have you found a solution for it. Because I have the same problem and I cannot fix it. I cannot run any project in XCODE. I restarted Xcode but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the max number of `pseudo terminals` by doing this:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.tty.ptmx_max=999
```

To make the change permanent beyond the current terminal session, do this:

```
sudo touch /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kern.tty.ptmx_max=999" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Credits go to bartoszj at https://www.pgs-soft.com/ios-ui-testing-and-why-it-does-not-always-work-a-k-a-pushing-the-limits-of-the-xctest-framework/

Comment: Holy crap, totally helped so far. Who knew pseudo terminal and its max limit. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I reset the iOS Simulator ("iOS Simulator" menu > "Reset Content and Settings..."), then I restarted Xcode.  These two combined resolved this issue for me.

I am using Xcode 6.0 beta 4.

Answer (score 1):

reset  the iphone simulator and then quit the simulator  then started it again  or XCode menu->Clear cache solved  your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is one little thing I would like to add if you're follow the guidance of: https://www.pgs-soft.com/ios-ui-testing-and-why-it-does-not-always-work-a-k-a-pushing-the-limits-of-the-xctest-framework/
Which BTW is brilliant that they figured that out (hint, hint Apple!) Its an exploit with a doubt, but a solution that works for now.

You do not have to create multiple test targets that run under a 160 tests each per target. My suggestion is to have the simulator run on a separate PID. Its as simple as

```
`set +e 
 killall "Simulator" 
 set -e
 xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace YourComapny.xcworkspace -scheme YourCompanyApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=latest' -only-testing:Test/testApp0`

`set +e 
 killall "Simulator" 
 set -e
 xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace YourComapny.xcworkspace -scheme YourCompanyApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=latest' -only-testing:Test/testApp1`
```

and so on. Each new `test-without-building` with the sim killed will force a new PID and you can avoid polluting your testing architechture with copied test targets.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this same problem.
After quit Xcode and Simulator,restart them several times, it still could't work.
Lastly, I solved this problem by doing this two steps:

1.**Power off** (Turn up the Mac volume,Shut down or restart Mac before saving your working files);
2.**Press “option + command + P + R”** at the same time after pressing Mac power switch，then you will hear the system launching sound——That means system is clearing caches safely，you can open your fingers after hearing two or three sounds. The system will go on launch normally.